# A Hint-System for Exercises

Tags: cross-referencing

A couple months ago, I read Euclidean Geometry in Math Olympiads by Evan Chen and he had a really cool hint system that I would like to incorporate as well. For many of the problems in the book, he provided hints, like here:

[image]

And then at the end of the book, he had them all listed up in increasing order. Now, I doubt that he would list the numbers out by hand, and that he would rather generate the numbers randomly and then refer to them with some command. However, I really have no idea how that could be done? Does anybody know a way to do that?

Comment: Start with reading the documentation of `hyperref` package, it should already do what you want I think. (in combination with an enumerate environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the hints so they have a label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=blue!60,
}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[section]
\newtheorem{hint}{Hint}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addhints}{m}
 {
  \unskip
  \space
  \mbox
   {
    \footnotesize
    \textbf{Hints:}~
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \ref{##1}~ }
    \unskip
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Problems}

\begin{problem}
Show that for something we have something else. \addhints{ab,uv}
\end{problem}

\section{Hints}

\begin{hint}\label{ab}
Remember that $1+1=2$
\end{hint}

\begin{hint}\label{cd}
Some complicated and useless hint.
\end{hint}

\begin{hint}\label{uv}
This hint is very useful.
\end{hint}

\end{document}
```

[image]